# Get only last updated row of joined table in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have below code for fetching data from DB,

```
        $invoices = SalesInvoices::where('is_invoice', 1)
        ->join('customers', 'customers.customer_id', '=', 'sales_invoices.customer_id')
        ->join('sales_payments', 'sales_payments.invoice_id', '=', 'sales_invoices.invoice_id')
        ->orderBy("sales_payments.created_at", "desc") //Get the latest updated payment for view in table for just 1 row.
        ->get();
```

`Sales_payments` table has a different stage of payments with multiple entries like Received, Partial, Completed, etc. and each stage data row has `invoice_id` which is the primary key of `SalesInvoices`.

Now I am showing all invoices in `DataTables`, but with the above code, I get all values of `sales_payments`, but I need only the last updated entry which has the latest `created_at`.

How can I get only one invoice row but the latest status of the payment in `Sales_payments`,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

there's multiple choice:
a. Its because you already order salespayment.created at desc, get the first

```
$invoices = SalesInvoices::where('is_invoice', 1)
        ->join('customers', 'customers.customer_id', '=', 'sales_invoices.customer_id')
        ->join('sales_payments', 'sales_payments.invoice_id', '=', 'sales_invoices.invoice_id')
        ->orderBy("sales_payments.created_at", "desc") //Get the latest updated payment for view in table for just 1 row.
        ->first();
```

b. Use Latest

```
$invoices = SalesInvoices::where('is_invoice', 1)
            ->join('customers', 'customers.customer_id', '=', 'sales_invoices.customer_id')
            ->join('sales_payments', 'sales_payments.invoice_id', '=', 'sales_invoices.invoice_id')
            ->latest('sales_payments.created_at')->first();
```

c. last

```
$invoices = SalesInvoices::where('is_invoice', 1)
            ->join('customers', 'customers.customer_id', '=', 'sales_invoices.customer_id')
            ->join('sales_payments', 'sales_payments.invoice_id', '=', 'sales_invoices.invoice_id')
            ->last();
```

Comment: This will result in only 1 invoice output if there are 10 invoices in ```SalesInvoices```

Comment: sorry, what are you trying to achieve? I mean like what is the output you hope?

Comment: I want to see all invoices but the sales_payment status should be the latest one in ```sales_payments``` coumn.

Comment: then you can perform 2 query. the first query get the sales payment status wich is the latest one, and then second query all the invoices where sales_payment like variable from the first query.